# Cassandra column update based on a value from other table which has mapping

Tags: cassandra

I have table # 1 which has a column to represent State value as IL, TX, CA. There is another table (table # 2) which has a mapping for States description like (IL, Illinois), (TX, Texas), (CA, California). I would like to add a new column StateDescription to Table# 1 and update the value based on StateDescription from Table# 2 for corresponding State field.
This is needed for approximately 500 million records. What is the best approach for handling the same?

Answer (score 0):

Add the column + write script in any language that have drivers for cassandra and update each row based on the logic you've described. You can implement parallel execution on portions of data for better throughput (if your cluster can take it).

You can also implement the logic using spark.